# Websites are not visible in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, web-hosting, iis-10

In IIS Manager I only see add connection, Other option like default website, add new website are not available. Although everything is installed in order (checked through "Turn windows feature on or off").

[image]

Its windows 10 and IIS version is as below

[image]

Any Clue , how can to get default web site in IIS or add new website here ?

Comment: If you are curious enough to create a connection to localhost, you will see the magic afterwards.

Comment: @LexLi , no I am not curious for such magic. I want to host two .net core api as  application

Comment: Did you run IIS manager as administrator? Non-admin user won't see any sites unless administrator deletegate specific one on IIS manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour occurs when you start IIS manager as a standard user. As a standard user you can connect to remote IIS server using credentials, but you can never manage the local IIS instance.

Start IIS Manager as administrator